Unable to publish data into SQL Server using SSIS
I am trying to publish a locally stored csv table to SQL Server using SSIS. I have created a table in SQL server using the below query on SSMS.
The sample rows can be found in the link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zV1tuyK_kuFgXeaXHQHygosvZuDwuR5e/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=116731415262785172646&rtpof=true&sd=true
use sample_superstore

drop table dbo.orders;

create table dbo.orders
(
    "Order_ID" varchar(50),
    "Order_Date" date null,
    "Ship_Date" date null,
    "Ship_Mode" varchar(50),
    "Customer_ID" varchar(50),
    "Country" varchar(50),
    "City" varchar(50),
    "Product_ID" varchar(50),
    "Category" varchar(50),
    "Sub-Category" varchar(50),
    "Product_Name" nvarchar(150)
);

select * from dbo.orders;

I am getting these errors:

Error: 0xC020901C at Upload Data, OLE DB Destination [62]: There was an error with OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input].Columns[Order Date] on OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input].
The column status returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".
Error: 0xC0209029 at Upload Data, OLE DB Destination [62]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR. The "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC0209077 occurred, and the error row disposition on "OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component. There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
Error: 0xC0047022 at Upload Data, SSIS.Pipeline: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED. The ProcessInput method on component "OLE DB Destination" (62) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "OLE DB Destination Input" (75). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running. There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

I need some help with this.
Thank you.
To tried resolving this by changing the data type to DT_DATE.

' csv table' ? Please publish a few rows as text,

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Is it possible that Order_Date should be datetime2? It will be usefule to see sample data.

DT_DATE A date structure that consists of year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds, and fractional seconds.  DATE - yyyy-MM-dd your data needs to be compatible with the table datatype.

Just for testing purposes, can you try putting nvarchar(max) or varchar(max) to all of textual columns and datetime2 for dates?
Error log clearly states that the column size is not enough:
The column status returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data."

@P.Salmon I have added an image of example rows. Hope this helps in resolving.
Thanks,
S

@user_0, I have added few rows as example now.
Thanks,
S

Unlike text we can't use images to reproduce your problem. The dates in the image are not valid sql server dates (yyyy-mm-dd) you either need to transform them at source, transform using ssis or load to varchar and transform later, You could also load to a staging table tidy up in sql and insert to the final table.

@P.Salmon, thanks for pointing that out. I've shared a link to the sample rows for reproducing this.

The dates in your sample data look like they are in DD/MM/YYYY, which probably doesn't jive with the locality settings of the db. I would suggest transforming the dates to MM/DD/YYYY or YYYY-MM-DD format. Might be easiest to import to a staging table as a varchar, and then post-process for the transform.
